# Outlier removal (outlierMAD command in pracma package)

Tags: r, error-handling, dataset, package, outliers

I would like to remove outliers from each column of my dataset... By searching the web, seems the Hampel Identifier should be a good solution to my problem, which has an outlier detection technique:   `[median – t * MAD, median + t * MAD]`.

With the instruction provided by: http://exploringdatablog.blogspot.com/2012/01/moving-window-filters-and-pracma.html  I would like to use the "outlierMAD" command to fulfill my task:

```
outlierMAD <- function (x, k){
   n <- length(x)
   y <- x
   ind <- c()
   L <- 1.4826
   t0 <- 3
   for (i in (k + 1):(n - k)) {
    x0 <- median(x[(i - k):(i + k)])
    S0 <- L * median(abs(x[(i - k):(i + k)] - x0))
    if (abs(x[i] - x0) > t0 * S0) {
        y[i] <- x0
        ind <- c(ind, i)
    }
   }
    list(y = y, ind = ind)
}
```

But I got an error when I try:

```
Error in if (abs(x[i] - x0) > t0 * S0) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can anyone help me on this? How can I avoid NAs in my data?

A link of my sample data can be found at: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86_a8ltyoL3NHNaeWk3d1QyQms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: duplicated of [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121071/can-we-use-leave-one-out-mean-and-standard-deviation-to-reveal-the-outliers/121075?noredirect=1#comment230920_121075).

Answer (score 1):

The logical value of abs(x[i] - x0) > t0 * S0 should be True or False. The error could happen if any of variables are NA or treated as non-numeric. 
In NA presence case, the median could produce NA instead of the median value if na.rm=FALSE.  Setting up na.rm=TRUE for median will fix X0 and S0, but doesn't help in logical expression above if x[I]=NA itself. 
Try to check your data on NA or some other non-numeric values. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using the hampel function of the 'pracma' package. The problem was caused by my time-series which has less than 5 observations. Check if yours is long enough.

Answer (score 0):

need to reduce the K value or else kept one condition if the nrow(df) > 5 then apply hample otherwise skip the hample and proceed the mean for those 5 sets